# Select2 - Listen on character input

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am trying to retrieve the text from the input field everytime this gets changed. I want to be able to listen to any character input. What I am trying to achieve is something similar to the listeners that textfields have:

```
  $("#text-field").on('input', function(){
     console.log('Hi');
  });
```

This code for example will print `Hi` in the console everytime a new character is entered or removed from the textfield.
Is it possible to achieve similar functionality for Select2 fields?

So far, I have tried all the built-in listeners provided by the library, such as `change` and `change.select2` but they will only trigger when an option gets selected.

This is what I have at the moment but does not do what I need at all.

```
  let selectField = $('#select-field').select2();

  selectField.on('change', function (e) {
    console.log('Hi');
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When do you want the listener to trigger?  I'm assuming you meant that you want it to change when they are selected or unselected?

Comment: I want them to trigger everytime a new character is being entered. The `change` listener that I have at the moment gets triggered everytime an option gets selected but that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Try $(".select2-search__field").on('input', function(){

Comment: This didn't work @Chris

Comment: Ok, use inspector in your browser and find the text input field that is being created by select2. You'll then be able to see the class or ID of this field. This is what you need to bind to.

Comment: `.select2-search__field` is the right class name for the field, I don't know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that eventually worked for me is this:

```
$(document).on('input', '.select2-search__field', function() {
  // Action here...
});
```

I know using `document` is not the best solution but the following did not work for me:

```
$('.select2-search__field').on('input', function() {
   // Action here...
});
```

If someone can provide a better solution, please feel free to do so.